# Неправильная перезапись информации в файл

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Задача: Создать програму, которая бы выполняла такие действия:

1) создание файла;
2) внесение информации;
3) просмотр содержимого файла;
4) внесение новых данных в файл;
5) поиск фамилий студентов, которые имеют хотя бы одну оценку “2”;
6) удаление данных из файла.

Проблема з 6 пунктом, после выполнения всех действий, описаных в этом пункте, в файле появляется очень много букв "М" и числа. Вот программа:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct results { // Описываем структуру из 3 пунктов
    char surname[20];
    char group[20];
    int marks[10];
};

void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char mas[2000], surname[12];
    char ch; int num, k, n, i, j = 0;

    int size = 2; // Количество студентов
    const int mark = 4; // Количество оценок
    results firstclass[10]; // Переменная для структуры
    char name[] = "Результаты сессии на первом курсе.txt"; // Названия 
                                                           // файлов
    char name2[] = "name2";

    cout << "0 - Создание файла;" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Запись данных в файл;" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Просмотр файла;" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Внесение новых данных в файл;" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Поиск студентов, которые имеют оценку '2';" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Удаление данных из файла;" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Выход из программы" << endl;

    do {
        cout << endl << "Выберите режим работы: ";
        cin >> num;
        cout << endl;

        if (num == 0) { // Создание файла
            ofstream File;
            File.open(name);
            File.close();
            cout << "Файл создан" << endl;
        }

        else if (num == 1) // Внесение данных 
        { 
            cout << "Введите информацию в файл:" << endl;
            ofstream File;
            File.open(name);
            File << "Фамилия";
            File << "   " << "Группа " << " ";
            File << "     " << "Оценки" << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { // Цикл для ввода данных про 
                                             // нескольких студентов
                cout << "Введите фамилию " << j + 1 << " студента: ";
                cin >> firstclass[j].surname;
                File << firstclass[j].surname << "   ";
                cout << "Введите группу студента: ";
                cin >> firstclass[j].group;
                File << "   " << firstclass[j].group;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // Цикл для 4 оценок каждого 
                                              // студента
                    cout << "Введите оценку студента по " << i + 1 << " предмету: ";
                    cin >> firstclass[j].marks[i];
                    File << "   " << firstclass[j].marks[i];
                }
                File << endl;
            }
            File.close();
        }

        else if (num == 2) //Вывод информации
        { 
            cout << "Информация из файла: " << endl;
            ifstream File;
            File.open(name);
            if (!File.is_open())
                cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!" << endl;
            else {
                while (File.get(ch)) { // Выводим информацию по одному 
                                       // символу
                    cout << ch;
                }
            }
            File.close();
        }

        else if (num == 3) // Внесение новых данных
        { 
            ofstream File;
            File.open(name, ofstream::app);
            cout << "Введите количество студентов, о которых нужно внести данные: ";
            cin >> n;
                // Далее так же как и в пункте 2
                for (int j = size; j < n + size; j++) { // Начинаем цикл с 
                                         //   числа = количеству студентов
                cout << "Введите фамилию " << j + 1 << " студента: ";
                cin >> firstclass[j].surname;
                File << "   " << firstclass[j].surname;
                cout << "Введите группу студента: ";
                cin >> firstclass[j].group;
                File << "   " << firstclass[j].group;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    cout << "Введите оценку студента по " << i + 1 << " предмету: ";
                    cin >> firstclass[j].marks[i];
                    File << "   " << firstclass[j].marks[i];
                }
                cout << endl;
                File << endl;
            }
            File.close();
            size += n; // Общее количество студентов увеличиваем на n
        }

        else if (num == 4) // Поиск студентов у которых есть двойка
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    if (firstclass[j].marks[i] == 2) { // Если i-ая оценка 
        // j-го студента = 2, то дальше выводим j-ю фамилию и прерываем цикл
                        cout << "Студент " << firstclass[j].surname << 
" имеет оценку 2" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        else if (num == 5) // Удаление информации из файла
        {
            cout << "Введите фамилию студента, информацию о котором нужно удалить: ";
            cin >> surname;
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {


  // Если строки surname, в которую мы ввели фамилию, и какая-то из фамилий 
  // структуре совпадают, то мы запоминаем в переменную k номер j-той фамилии 
                if (strcmp(firstclass[j].surname, surname) == 0) { 
                    k = j;
                }
            }

            ofstream File2; // Создаём и открываем новый файл
            File2.open(name2);
            File2 << "Фамилия";
            File2 << "   " << "Группа " << " ";
            File2 << "     " << "Оценки" << endl;

            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (j == k) continue; 

// Если j = k, то итеррацию
// пропускаем, тем самым не записываем в новый файл информацию про сказаного 
// ранее студента
                else {
                    File2 << "   " << firstclass[j].surname;
                    File2 << "   " << firstclass[j].group;
                    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        File2 << "   " << firstclass[j].marks[i];
                    }
                }

            }
            File2.close(); // Закрываем второй файл
            remove("Результаты сессии на первом курсе.txt"); // Удалаяем 
                                                             // первый
            rename(name2, name); // Переименовываем второй в первый
        }


        else if (num = 6) break;
    } while (true);
    system("pause");
}
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня ваша программа полностью работает

Замечания:
используйте `int main` вместо `void main`
добавьте `return 0;` в конец `main`

Comment: Спасибо, даже не подумал об этом